# C Program Slow Start in MacOS

Tags: c, gcc, macos-mojave

I'm following a tutorial in c programming, a very simple c file `hello.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num;
    printf("Hello world! Give me an integer:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Thanks! I've always been fond of %d.\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Source from: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall02/cos126/assignments/hello-osx.html

Then compile and run it in using `gcc hello.c` then `./a.out`
There seem to be a pause before I see `Hello world! Give me an integer:` from the time of `./a.out` and hit return.

Why is that so? And how to improve this startup?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the C code. It must be related to the time it takes for your OS to load and start the program. I don't think this question belongs on stackoverflow. Maybe https://serverfault.com/ could be a better place but I'm not sure